# Exception thrown when using multiple value-objects of same type in EF-Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, value-objects

I have this BankLayoutSettings entity (simplified for brevity):

```
public class BankLayoutSettings
{
    public Guid BankId { get; set; }
    public Color HeaderAndFooterBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public Color HeaderForeColor { get; set; }
    public Color FooterForeColor { get; set; }
    public Color TitlesForeColor { get; set; }
}
```

where Color looks like that (also simplified for brevity):

```
  [TypeConverter(typeof(ColorTypeConverter))]
  public sealed class Color
  {
    [UsedImplicitly]
    private string _hashPrefixedHexTriplet;

    public static Color FromHashPrefixedHexTriplet(string hashPrefixedHexTriplet)
    {
      return new Color(hashPrefixedHexTriplet);
    }

    private Color()
    {
    }

    private Color(string hashPrefixedHexTriplet)
    {
      _hashPrefixedHexTriplet = hashPrefixedHexTriplet;
    }

    public string ToHashPrefixedHexTriplet()
    {
      return _hashPrefixedHexTriplet;
    }
  }
```

And the TypeConverter looks like this:

```
  public class ColorTypeConverter : TypeConverter
  {
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
      return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
      if (value is string) return Color.FromHashPrefixedHexTriplet(value as string);

      return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
      if (destinationType == typeof(string)) return ((Color) value).ToHashPrefixedHexTriplet();
      return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
  }
```

It's setup like so in the DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BankLayoutSettings>(b =>
      {
        b.HasKey(x => x.BankId);
        b.OwnsOne(o => o.HeaderAndFooterBackgroundColor).Property("_hashPrefixedHexTriplet").HasColumnName(nameof(Domain.Model.BankLayoutSettings.HeaderAndFooterBackgroundColor));
        b.OwnsOne(o => o.HeaderForeColor).Property("_hashPrefixedHexTriplet").HasColumnName(nameof(Domain.Model.BankLayoutSettings.HeaderForeColor));
        b.OwnsOne(o => o.FooterForeColor).Property("_hashPrefixedHexTriplet").HasColumnName(nameof(Domain.Model.BankLayoutSettings.FooterForeColor));
        b.OwnsOne(o => o.TitlesForeColor).Property("_hashPrefixedHexTriplet").HasColumnName(nameof(Domain.Model.BankLayoutSettings.TitlesForeColor));
      });
```

To persist it, I first set the BankId to an existing bank's id and then call _context.Add(bankLayoutSettings) followed by _context.SaveChanges. That last call throws this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity of
>   'BankLayoutSettings.HeaderAndFooterBackgroundColor#Color' is sharing
>   the table 'BankLayoutSettings' with 'BankLayoutSettings', but there is
>   no entity of this type with the same key value
>   'BankLayoutSettingsBankId:1f397108-3769-4511-f8a3-08d5bb30d71a' that
>   has been marked as 'Added'.

The weird thing is that the Guid is not the one I set on the bankLayoutSettings.BankId. While debugging and peeking at the changed entries (ChangeTracker.Entries), I found that the first Color property (HeaderAndFooterBackgroundColor) had its BankId member set to the correct bank id (the one I set) while the other Color properties had random Guids. And I don't understand why, as all Color properties have the exact same treatment throughout the code.

So then I modified my entity to only include the first Color property, and sure enough, that worked fine without throwing the exception.

Am I doing something wrong ? Am I hitting an unsupported scenario with EF Core 2.0 ?

And moreover, how can I make this work correctly ?

EDIT:

The relationship from Bank to BankLayoutSettings is setup like so:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<BankLayoutSettings>(b =>
    {
      b.HasOne<Bank>()
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<BankLayoutSettings>(x => x.BankId);
    }
  );
```

Comment: I think the `Guid` type PK property is treated as auto-generated by convention. Try adding `b.Property(x => e.BankId).ValueGeneratedNever();`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just tried that but unfortunately I still get the same exception.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: Actually I cannot access the actual Color's BankId property because it only exists in the EF Core related entry, not in the model. So when I do a `b.Property(x => e.BankId).ValueGeneratedNever();`, I'm accessing the `BankLayoutSettings.BankId`, not the Color's `BankId`

Comment: Please show how you configured the relationship between `Bank` and `BankLayoutSettings`. Looks like it's not properly set up. Also, which part of Color is actually stored in the database? The code you show doesn't have any properties EF could map as database fields.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: I've added the Bank to BankLayoutSettings relationship setup in the question. For the Color, it's the `_hashPrefixedHexTriplet` private field that's used and setup like described in the code: `b.OwnsOne(o => o.HeaderForeColor).Property("_hashPrefixedHexTriplet").HasColumnName(nameof(Domain.Model.BankLayoutSettings.HeaderForeColor));`

Comment: Ah, OK, an "encapsulated property". These new features keep coming :). The configuration looks OK. I was just wondering why the exception mentions "BankLayoutSettingsBankId", apparently a small string concatenation error in EF's code, but quite deceptive.

Comment: It works for me (EFC 2.0.3). Is `BankLayoutSettings` entity related to some other entity (like `Bank` with one-to-one)? Can you provide a repro (you can remove converter because it's irrelevant to the issue).

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: Like described in my last edit, BankLayoutSettings is related to the Bank with a one-to-one relationship. I'm not sure about what you call a repro and how to share that. Shall I create a new VS solution ? But then should I share it on github or is there a simpler way to do that ?

Comment: Ok, there's a repro on https://github.com/daniel-jann/ef-core-value-object.

Comment: Ok, I've found what's going wrong. As null value objects are not supported by EF Core, I'm using an empty Color object (Color.Empty) which is setting its _hashPrefixedHexTriplet field to null. When using Empty Colors, it fails with the exception, but when using non-empty colors, it does actually work. So I guess I could set the _hashPrefixedHexTriplet to something else than null (ie empty string) and it would work... I'm just not very happy with that solution as I'll have empty strings in the DB instead of nulls...

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work correctly even when using empty strings.